# ssh failing on a user with a password that contains special char on the first symbol

Tags: linux, ssh, centos, ssh-keys

When trying to do: ssh -oBatchMode=yes -4 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null

ssh fails when the password of the remote linux user starts with a special char(for example !Passw0rd) and shows the following error: "Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)"

When creating a user with password such as Passw0rd! it works properly.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: how can it be solved? why it happens?

Comment: There's something fishy. The `permission denied` message does not mention `password`. It mentions `publickey`; this method [can ask for the passphrase](https://superuser.com/a/1576115/432690). And it mentions `gssapi-*`; this one I don't know, but [it *seems* it shouldn't ask](https://serverfault.com/a/329910). Anyway, **the `password` method was not used**. So *maybe* you were asked for something else. Or *maybe* the question contains misleading or incomplete information.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but I have tried your example on my RHEL 7 servers running openSSH version 7.4pl-16 and I did not have any error using same password as you starting with !...

Maybe you have a typo with the password or keyboard settings? Try to use scp for example and confirm if the problem still exist even using scp?