# ssh key authentication login not working

Tags: ssh

I generated new ssh keys. push the public key to my server. set my ssh directory ownership to 700 and all the files in that directory to 600. logged out then tried to log back in and it still asks for a password and when I try to enter the correct password I get back "permission denied, please try again". So now my ssh key or my original password is not working. can anyone tell me what Im doing wrong??

Comment: Three ideas: (1) A typo in the username. (2) Wrong server. (3) It's asking for a [passphrase](https://superuser.com/a/1576115/432690) which happens to be different than your password.

Comment: thanks for the advice. I had the username wrong