# Passwordless SSH connection still asks for a password

Tags: linux, ssh, kali-linux, openssh, wsl2

I wanted to set up a distributed environment for MPI, I followed this [tutorial](https://mpitutorial.com/tutorials/running-an-mpi-cluster-within-a-lan/),
I'm starting with 2 machines only:

- manager: `@ip1`, username:`mpiuser`
- worker: `@ip2`, username:`mpiuser`

the manager is running `ubuntu wsl2`, and the worker is running `kali-Linux`.
the problem is I can't figure out why the passwordless ssh is not working, I am always asked to enter the worker's password.
Steps followed:

1. `$ ssh-keygen -t dsa`
2. `$ ssh-copy-id worker`
3. `$ ssh worker`

I would like to get a more detailed description of the steps to understand exactly what I am doing and figure out what I am doing wrong, as it is my first time trying to set up passwordless ssh.

edit:
providing `ssh -v worker`

```
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to worker [192.168.1.13] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/mpiuser/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mpiuser/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mpiuser/.ssh/id_dsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/mpiuser/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mpiuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mpiuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mpiuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mpiuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mpiuser/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mpiuser/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mpiuser/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mpiuser/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mpiuser/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mpiuser/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.7p1 Debian-2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.7p1 Debian-2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to worker:22 as 'mpiuser'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:86s83qUrbF48/qRSD7Uwn1XkMFJVhOeqScgVdCt8CEY
debug1: Host 'worker' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/mpiuser/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Skipping ssh-dss key /home/mpiuser/.ssh/id_dsa - not in PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/mpiuser/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/mpiuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/mpiuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/mpiuser/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/mpiuser/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/mpiuser/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/mpiuser/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/mpiuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/mpiuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /home/mpiuser/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /home/mpiuser/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /home/mpiuser/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Next authentication method: password
mpiuser@worker's password:
```

Comment: Please confirm this is indeed about the password, not about the passphrase. Compare [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1576115/432690).

Comment: `ssh worker` asks for: `mpiuser@worker's password:`

Comment: Please [edit] the question and provide the output of `ssh -v worker` in the point 3.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski edited as you asked, thanks for your time.

Comment: I think the problem is in the line that says `Skipping ssh-dss key`. You specifically requested `dsa` when creating the key. See `man 5 ssh_config`, the option you need is `PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes`; or consider creating and using a key of a type that is accepted by default. This is not an answer because I cannot guide you in details, but I'm pretty sure the lead is good.

Comment: ok, thank you I will try that and write an answer if could solve the problem, thanks for the lead.